# CPLEX oplrun says the problem size has exceeded, but then proceeds to solve the problem anyway

Tags: cplex, opl

I have downloaded and installed the CPLEX Studio Community Edition 20.1.0.0 on my Linux machine (KUbuntu). I want to use the `oplrun` tool directly from the terminal. I can run it just fine. However, at the start of the program, it displays a message that says:

```
IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio Community Edition.  The CPLEX Optimizers will solve problems up to 1000 variables and 1000 constraints.
Problem size limit exceeded.
CP Optimizer Community Edition solves problems with search spaces up to 2^1000.
Unrestricted version options (including academia) at https://ibm.co/2s0wqSa
```

The message appears whatever input I use, and then, weirdly enough, it proceeds to solve the problem. I've tested with many different OPL examples at `<install-dir>/opl/examples/opl`. The above message in particular appeared when I used the input files at `<install-dir>/opl/examples/opl/knapsack`, which is a small example with just a few variables. So I have two questions:

1. Why does this message appear?
2. Why it proceeds to solve the problem if the problem is "supposedly" too large? Is the solution returned valid?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. My suggestion would be to ask on the IBM Decision Optimization forum (https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer?communitykey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7&tab=digestviewer) (registration required).

Comment: At first I went to one of IBM forums, one in which it was not enough to be registered to post a question. Then I gave up. Now I followed your link and posted my question there. Waiting.

Comment: Link to the question in IBM forum : https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=5557&MessageKey=aec2c819-d079-4308-8052-f315b80e95fb&CommunityKey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7&tab=digestviewer&ReturnUrl=%2fcommunity%2fuser%2fdatascience%2fcommunities%2fcommunity-home%2fdigestviewer%3fcommunitykey%3dab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7%26tab%3ddigestviewer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed even for models that are small enough like knapsack you get the message

> IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio Community Edition.  The CPLEX
> Optimizers will solve problems up to 1000 variables and 1000
> constraints. Problem size limit exceeded. CP Optimizer Community
> Edition solves problems with search spaces up to 2^1000. Unrestricted
> version options (including academia) at https://ibm.co/2s0wqSa

but you should not see

> Problem size limit exceeded.

That's a bug. But it is normal to be able to solve this with the [FREE CPLEX community edition](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-free-ibm-cplex-alex-fleischer/).